# React setState issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
fetch('http://192.168.0.113:8000/api/v1/react/fetch_conversation_action/')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(action => this.setState({action}, () => console.log(action)))

    console.log(this.state);
```

i am making a fetch call to an API  i get the response but what happens is i have to set the  state  but it is not happening  i know react setState  is one step late in setting state i am able to log the value  to the console but whaen it comes to set state it does not updates the state

Comment: Please post the rest of the component where the state and the fetch is in.

Comment: can you add your full component ?

Comment: its because the `setstate` written at the end of the code is called first. because fetch is async

Comment: How do you know the state is not updated?

Comment: You are not setting any state in this snippet! It should be e. g. `this.setState({ action: action })`. Your `{ action }` argument is trying to pull out `action` property from the current state, it is not setting anything.

Comment: @hannadrehman The state is not set in the snippet before the promise by `fetch`is resolved.

Comment: @HynekS `thisState({action})` in the snippet is valid. `action` is the parameter of the `action => ...` arrow function and `{action}` is shorthand for `{action: action}`.

Comment: @Sami Oh, you are right, my mistake, that is not the issue.